# Decode hex chars in string

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

From a third part i get a string like this `"123123&#x4;"`
Ill have to wrap it into some XML however i get this error `System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character.`

Can I either decode the hex value to something meaningful, or just delete it. The solution must be able to handle other hex values as well.

Comment: Well what are you trying to do at the moment? What does your code look like? Do you actually want to capture the string as-is (e.g. by encoding the `&` as `&amp;`) or are you trying to treat that as an XML element value? (If so, you need to accept that it's simply not valid...)

Comment: Im trying to add "123123&#x4;" as an element value, however i wasnt expecting the string to contain &#x4; or any other hex values. The hex does not make any sence and is properly an copy paste error from a user

Comment: That's the EOT/end-of-transmission character so you can't decode it into something that has a visual meaning. As its on the end of the string you could assume its an artifact of the third party and just replace &#x4; with nothing.

Comment: @AlexK. The problem is next time they might copy/paste &#x3; or &#x5; so i have to come up with a more general replace algoritm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating this method

```
public static string RemoveInvalidXmlChars(string str)
{

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var decodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);

    foreach (var c in decodedString)
    {
        if (XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(c))
            sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```